# How to juggle part-time job stress with study?

Tags: work-environment

I'm studying Computer science second year). I applied for a part-time job at MacDonalds, 6 hoursper day, 3 days per week. I thought that will not affect my study but I started to feel tired and the work was so stressful that I quit after the first week. When I did that the supervisor of the restaurant told me "you will never succeed in your life because you are so soft". His words stuck in my head and keep repeated I realized I'm so soft. How do I improve my hard working skills?

Comment: this is a fair question, downvoters are wrong - maybe it can be reworded to something a little more general and a little more about working a second job (i mean, i know the OP is in uni, but let's say uni is the first, main, job). But downvotes? No.

Comment: *Do not crosspost* http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/12161/how-to-work-under-pressure

Comment: Did you ask your manager why he thought that you were weak? I mean, did he give you any examples? It's hard to give you advice with such a general statement

Comment: Is your question about dealing with the workload and stress of the part-time job, or financial stresses, or the manager's obnoxious parting comment (if so, forget that, if that's how he retains employees he's pathetic).

Comment: Not an answer: but may I suggest sticking it out for a month if you try again? A new job is tiring as there is so much to learn, plus a change of routine to handle. Typically you'll feel most tired after 1-2 weeks, then adapt to the new routine. As you settle into a job, you have less to learn so it requires less concentration, and you become less tired.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You already learned that you can't live if there is too much pressure. That's normal. Actually nobody can live with too much pressure, just people have different levels of "too much". Full time university course plus 18 hours a week in a physical job is too much for you - that's normal and nothing to worry about.

From your post it seems that your manager's words affected you quite strongly. That's a problem for you. You see, the problem is not what he said. The problem is how it affected you. You can't influence what he said, but you can influence how it affects you. When he says "you are too weak" it doesn't mean you are too weak - it means he thinks you are too weak. That's an *enormous* difference. It's just his opinion. Do you care? When you are finished with your studies and have a good job, you can go back to his McDonald's shop, order a dozen hamburgers, give them away to kids in the street, and tell him that you can afford it because you make twice as much money as he does. (Well, don't do it, because that would be very rude, but you know that you *can* do it). So how much does his opinion count?

So that's something you need to work on. The chain was: He says "you're too weak" -> You think "I'm too weak". The chain should be: He says "you're too weak" -> You hear what he says -> You realise it's just his opinion -> You realise that he has no idea how hard you work on your university course -> You realise that he is completely wrong -> You realise there is no point in upsetting him or starting an argument -> You say "Yes, sir" while thinking to yourself "if only you knew how hard I'm working at university" and walk away.

Comment: I'm in two minds with this answer. I agree with the whole "believe in yourself" part, but I wonder whether the manager may actually have a point about OP.

Comment: @l19 I really don't think so. Chances are that the manager was rather unprofessional and pissed off because of the short employment time (or he is of flawed character, who knows). If my part time job was effecting my studies at the university, I'd do exactly the same. I actually did, and am in a good position right now because of it. :-)

Comment: It is quite common that a manager would only know his own little world. If he said "you aren't doing a good job here", he would probably be right because you can state that without considering the person's situation. He said "you are too weak to succeed" which needed to take in the whole situation of that person (like studying full time at university), which most likely he didn't.

Answer (score 7):

McD is a tough gig. Maybe you should have started with 6 hours just one day a week. Customer facing retail work can be exhausting - I'd rather dig ditches, it's less tiring :)

Try again, but start from one day per week. If you want to stay in fast food, that is.

Most white collar jobs are nowhere as stressful as customer facing retail. You are probably better off participating in your university's Work Study program, which is geared to the needs of full-time college students and where the jobs won't exhaust you - In some cases, you might even be able to study while working :) You just found out the hard way that entry-level jobs in fast food are geared to the needs of the fast food industry, just as the job of galley slave was geared to the needs of the galley owners - in one case, you work until you drop. In the other case, you row until you die. No previous experience required :)

Either you've already got plenty of pressure or you are going to get plenty of pressure as a CS major - so far, you seem to handling it. Your manager said you are too soft, but I'd like him to keep up the trash talk as a CS major. The problem is not that you can't handle pressure - you have yet to prove you can't - or that you are too soft. The problem is that working in fast food requires you to have some phenomenal physical endurance and you apparently don't have it. In other words, the fast food job was a bad fit for you. Even if you had that physical endurance, it is still questionable whether the job is a good fit for you as a full-time university student because of the requirement that you have to run around like a headless chicken during your entire work shift.

Answer (score 3):

When I was in high school, I did a similar thing, except I took 4-hour days 3-4 days a week plus longer days during the weekend. And about a decade later, I worked full time and did a half-speed university class in the evening. In both cases, it was **very** tiring, especially when I was having a lot of homework.

You're not a bad person for choosing to spend your energy on your studies instead of working at McD. It's heavy work, and you receive a lot of unpleasantness. You may simply be a person who isn't suited for that particular type of stress, rather than being a "soft" or "weak" person. Also, your supervisor is obviously not a very good manager because that is a really unpleasant thing to say to somebody.

The things you need to learn in order to handle stress are to some extent things that you can learn at the university. Focus on one thing at a time - if you've got two papers to write, start on one of them and do it well and disregard the other. If you can't meet a deadline, talk to the person who's expecting you to turn in your work. Get enough sleep and exercise, both of those contribute to being able to handle stress.

Working at a job you hate with rude people and a manager who doesn't know how to manage isn't going to help you get better at it. The one thing you *have* learned there is to recognize your limits and set boundaries when you need to. **That** is something that will help you later on!

Answer (score 2):

Working with people is very stressful. I worked fulltime server for 4 months and after that I was diagnosed with neurosis.

My advice would be to try to find something related to your job (maybe an IT internship or try some basic webdev freelancing).

Anyway, if you think that working with people is not the reason, I would also recommend checking with a doctor just in case you are starting to get some symptoms of depression/fatigue/anxiety but are dismissing them at this point. You might be just reacting wrongly to stress.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that the current answers are focused on reducing workload, migrating to other fields and or  whether the manager was right or wrong.

I'm more interested in answering your question.

> How to work under pressure?

They key is to do the next thing. You have a certain amount of tasks to do. Stress and worrying is nothing but panicking chaos; you desperately try to think of an overall solution to all of your problems, making you blind because you're not able to get the perfect overview. You begin to feel that you won't be able to do any of it. You collapse.

They key to stop worrying (and therefor allowing you to work under "pressure") is to prioritize your tasks and you pick the one with the highest priority and you **focus on that task until it's completed**. Before you know there is one less task to be done, you'll be able to go to the next one and you ignore the ones until it's their turn. Sure, sometimes you must work at two things at a time, but that's based on their priorities.

What happens now? You complete everything there can be completed, if there's something left then you realize that there was **nothing you could have done to change that**, but you could have spent an **awful amount of time** worrying about those tasks.

People spend too much time worrying about tasks that can not be completed, time that could have been spent on other tasks. Often times, more often than not, **you end up doing much more than you would have dreamed of because you didn't waste time stressing about it**.

Accept that worst possible outcome (it sucks sometimes, but accepting your worst possible fate will cleanse every bit of stress because you've accepted what might happen, instead of worrying about it) and spend your time on solving the problems that you can solve.

I recommend taking a look at Dale Carnegie's [book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Stop_Worrying_and_Start_Living) which focuses on making you realize how you can stop worrying and how pointless it actually is.

This methodology works for me (I finished college in 200% speed and had a 140% workload in my last year of uni, along with having side projects. And of course, everyone have personal problems; using this methodology has been a deal-breaker for me).

Good luck, I hope that this helps.